# Clearcase: findmerge usage

Tags: clearcase

I have a branch B1 and another branch B2. I want all files/subfolders (recursively) inside a particular folder X (and not on entire VOB) on B1 to be merged onto B2.

What exact findmerge command do I need to use?

The below commands will work for entire vob or if I run them by getting into the directory in question, that will suffice for me?

```
cleartool findmerge . -type dir -nc -fver .../dev/LATEST -merge
cleartool findmerge . -nc -type file -fver .../dev/LATEST -print
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4):

After checkin the **[`findmerge` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm)**:

You shouldn't need to merge first the directories, then the files.
`findmerge` should do the right merges (directories, then files) all by itself.

```
cleartool findmerge . -nc -fver .../dev/LATEST -merge
```

should be enough.

```
cleartool findmerge . -nc -fver .../dev/LATEST -print
```

will print what needs to be merged, but will stop at the directories.