# ClearCase - Is it possible to see new files in integration branch without merging?

Tags: clearcase

I am still new to using ClearCase, so please pardon if this question is (for a lack of a better term) dumb.

I tried searching first, but am having trouble describing / finding info about it (overshadowing and eclipsed is not quite what I am looking for).

The question is simply this:  **Is it possible to setup my config spec, such that I can see new files from an integration branch when I am set into my view and my branch?**

I find it often necessary to manually "merge down" into my branch in order to use/see any new files committed by other developers, which seems cumbersome.

Here's the branching structure

```
MAIN -- release_integration -- projA_release... -- <<specific work_tix branches>>
```

And the config spec I use

```
 element * CHECKEDOUT
 element * .../work_tix_12345/LATEST
 element * .../projA_release_integration/LATEST
 element * .../projA_release_integration/LATEST -mkbranch work_tix_12345
 element * .../release_integration/LATEST -mkbranch projA
 element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch release_integration
 ##element * .../release_integration/LATEST
 element * /main/LATEST
```

**Update:**
An example of what I mean by manually merging "down". See the merge back to the `work_tix_2` branch. Otherwise, I cannot see any new files added from `work_tix_3`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*New* files from an integration (`release_integration` or `projA_release_integration`) won't have version in `work_tix_12345` branch yet.

Considering your config spec, that means you should see those version immediately when they are created.

If you are talking about new *versions* in integration branch, for files which are *already* being modified in `work_tix_12345`, then yes, you won't see those version right away.
A [`cleartool findmerge -print`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730294/clearcase-findmerge-usage/2730665#2730665) would let you know if there are new versions to be considered.

Comment: About the first point, I am finding that I *cannot* see the new files unless I specifically merge the directory back to my branch (see added screenshot).  Is this avoidable?

Comment: @user1766760 it is avoidable if you modify your config spec in order to select first `work_tix_3/LATEST`.

Comment: Thanks. I talked with my group's ClearCase focal and understand that in this instance, my prior check-in IS preventing me from seeing the new files (which is also what you alluded to above).