# Add existing element to an existing dir on main

Tags: clearcase

I have a `dA/fC@@/main/0` that was created from a new file added to `dA@@/main/branchA/3`. The new file on `branchA` became `dA/fC@@/main/branchA/1`

Successive changes on `dA/fC@@/main/branchA/1` eventually end up on last version of `dA/fC@@/main/branchA/17`.

Then  `dA/fC@@/main/branchA/17` were merge from `branchA` into main creating `dA/fC@@/main/1`.

However `dA/fC@@/main/1` does not belong to any version of `dA@@main/*`.

I want to add `dA/fC@@/main/1` to `dA@@/main/40` so `dA@@/main/41` will contain `dA/fC@@/main/1`.

What are the ClearCase console commands to run on linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the destination view selects `/main/LATEST`, and the version created will be the one expected.

Main advice: use a different view for the merge, one which is configure to

```
element * /main/LATEST
```

Or create a new one, preferably a dynamic one.

**For a single file, once merged, you need to merge its parent folder too** (or you won't find a version of that folder listing that file at the right version)

On the destination view, display the version tree of that parent folder, right-click on the version where fC was recorded (`dA@@/main/branchA/4`), select merge to, and click on version `40`.

See also "[How files and directories are merged](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/how_merge_file_dir.htm)".

[image: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/images/merge_algorithm.gif]

> Each version of a Rational ClearCase directory element contains the names of certain file elements, directory elements, and VOB symbolic links.

---

Now, if you are sure merging `branchA` was about `fC` only, you could have done the merge of the file *and* its parent folder in one command: [**`cleartool findmerge`**](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm).
See "[ClearCase: `findmerge` usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2730665/6309)"

```
cd /path/to/view/avob/dA
cleartool findmerge . -nc -fver .../branchA/LATEST -merge
```

That would have merged `fC` and `dA`.

Comment: I only want to get `dA/fC@@main/1` to main, however from the target view (main) I don't see any version of `dA/fC`

Comment: @jessarah You need first to use the right view. Then the easiest way is to diqplay the version tree of that file, right-click on the version one, select merge to, and click on version 40.

Comment: VonC Thanks for your tips. Ver 1 is the file `fc` on main, Version 40 is the directory `dC` on main w/o `fC`. The file had already been merge into main/1, however it was missing from main because `dC@@main/40` did not contain `fC`. I would like to know how to directly add `fC@@main/1` to dA w/o creating a new elem with same name. Merge in a way does that however if I had more files added it would bring more files and I am interested in only one. Yes then i could remove the other files. However I think there must be a command to say `dA` display `fC` w/o using merge...

Comment: @jessarah right, I missed the dC parent folder part. I have rewritten the answer for you to select. I have added links to other of my answers on the same topic, as well as some documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I used the merge GUI to merge the version of `dA@@/main/branchA/4` where `dA/fC` was first added into dA@@/main/40 check-out.

This added `dA/fC` to the main view that is configured to get `element * main/LATEST`

I see now `dA/fC@@/main/1` on main and can commit.