# Best method to combine two views into a single view on clearcase

Tags: view, build, compilation, clearcase

What is the best method to combine two views in the same vob into one view? Each view may have a subset of different files.

Answer (score 0):

Use araxis merge or some tool like that. Merge files from one view to another. Complie and run tests. And do checkin if all right.

Consider to migrate hisory to git repo. I have done that with https://github.com/charleso/git-cc. But I have make some code hacking especially for my process.

Answer (score 0):

The ClearCase way (without having to use other tools or migrate to other SCM) would be **[`cleartool findmerge`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm)**
(and that would have the added benefit of a three-way merge instead of a two-way with other non-ClearCase merge tool)

See "[findmerge usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2730665/6309)", in your case:

```
cd /path/to/second/view
cleartool findmerge . -nc -ftag tag_of_first_view -merge
# test and check-in
```

Answer (score 0):

If each has a sub set of files that does not have any intersections, (unlikely, but possible, particularly if these subsets represent different "components" (UCM or otherwise), you may want to review the view configurations.

If these are dynamic views, you can run:

```
cleartool catcs -tag view1 > view1.txt
cleartool catcs -tag view2 > view2.txt
cleartool diff -gra view1.txt view2.txt
```

to get a side-by-side compare with differences. You could then plan which versions to select.

Merge is definitely a good option, but you would have to preview the merge as -- unlike most other SCM tools, CC versions directories, and if the views see different branches of the same directories, and files that are currently visible in one branch were removed from the other, files could "disappear" on merge. They will still be there, you may have to link them back in...